# Subspace of a finite dimensional dual space that separates points

Tags: linear-algebra

As i was reading i came across a statement of this kind:
If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and E is a subspace of its dual $V^*$, $E\le V^*$ and $E$ separates points than $E=V^*$.

I understand why that should be at intuitive level but i can't formalize my thoughts.. I have a feeling its a special (and more simple) case of some more general result.

Please help,

Thank you.

Comment: Try showing that $E$ contains enough linearly independent vectors by separating a basis for $V$

Comment: @Callus why don't you post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the $E\ne V^*$, and let $\{e_1^*,\ldots,e^*_k\}$ be a basis of $E$. Extend this to a basis $\{e_1^*,\ldots,e^*_k,e^*_{k+1},\ldots,e^*_n\}$ of $V^*$. Then pick a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$
of $V$ which is dual to $\{e_1^*,\ldots,e^*_n\}$, i.e.,
$$
e_i^*(e_j)=\delta_{ij}.
$$
Clearly, $x^*(e_{j+1})=0$, for all $x^*\in E$.

Thus $E=V^*$.